# artisan migration error “Class 'Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOMySql\\Driver' not found”

Tags: php, laravel, migration

When trying to run a migration I get the error Artisan migration

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
>
> Class 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver' not found

i already installed doctrine/dbal using

> composer require doctrine/dbal

and on my composer.json already had

> doctrine/dbal": "^3.0"

but i still got this error

Comment: if does not work. just reinstall composer by using composer install

Comment: if i reinstall, will it reset the composer? i mean will it delete other packages that i already installed?

Comment: yes it will reinstall inside on your composer.json

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This new version is having this issue.
a workaround for that can be:

1. change version to `"doctrine/dbal": "^2.12.1"` in composer.json file
2. run `composer update`

Comment: i figured this out yesterday but thank you for the answer

Answer (score 15):

```
"composer require doctrine/dbal ^2.12.1"
```

In updated versions of doctrine/dbl, Integration with PDO has been reworked. The php_pdo extension is no longer a hard dependency of the doctrine/dbal package. The PDO API is not longer the standard for DBAL APIs.

- The following database platforms are no longer supported:
  ( Drizzle, MariaDB 10.0 and older, Microsoft Azure, PostgreSQL 9.3 and older, SQL Anywhere, SQL Server 2008 and older.)
- The following drivers are no longer supported:
  ( pdo_ibm, sasql. )
- Passing a PDO instance initialized outside of the DBAL is no longer supported.

Here is the reference document (https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/releases)

Comment: I am using Laravel 7.x and it comes with `"doctrine/dbal": "^2.12"`. Somehow I ended up with "doctrine/dbal": "^3.x" and had to downgrade to 2.12 for it to work.